# Path finding in grid

Tags: recursion, graph-theory, graph-traversal

I trying to print all the paths in a mxm matrix which terminate if I visit an already visited node. I have tried a recursive solution but i am not sure how to handle the base case

```
def is_valid_move(x, y):
    return 0 <= x < m and 0 <= y < m
def find_paths(G, x, y, visited, path):
        visited.add((x, y))
        path.append((x, y))

        if len(visited) == m:
            return [path]# Print the path when all nodes are visited
        else:
            paths = []
            for dx, dy in [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]:
                nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
                if is_valid_move(nx, ny) and (nx, ny) not in visited:
                    new_paths = find_paths(G, nx, ny, set(visited), list(path))
                    paths.append(new_paths)

                if is_valid_move(nx, ny) and (nx, ny) in visited:
                    completed_path = [vertex for vertex in path]
                    paths.append(completed_path.append((nx, ny)))
            return paths

G = [['ghargh', 'drwtex', 'qdgeun'], ['xmhjkl', 'kmswji', 'cvjosd'], ['vbrmwq', 'fgdhey', 'eyuite']]
result_paths = find_paths(G, 0, 0, set(), [])
```

This code will give me paths which are of length m. But I also want paths which terminate earlier.
For example if I start at (0,0) the following path should also be present in all the possible paths (0,0)->(0,1)->(0,2)->(1,2)->(2,2)->(2,1)->(1,1)->(0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
if is_valid_move(nx, ny) and (nx, ny) in visited:
    completed_path = [vertex for vertex in path]
    paths.append(completed_path.append((nx, ny)))
```

First of all, there's no need to say `[vertex for vertex in path]`; that's just going to create a copy of `path`, so use `path`. Secondly, since `(nx, ny)` has already been visited, you shouldn't append it to `completed_path` (otherwise it wouldn't be a path). Finally, you should know that `foo.append(bar)` returns `None` in Python. Therefore, in the last line of the code block above, you're appending `None` to `paths` (and then returning `paths` after the if statement). The code block above should be changed as follows:

```
if is_valid_move(nx, ny) and (nx, ny) in visited:
    paths.append(path)
```